# How to compare two fields from different MongoDB Collections

Tags: mongodb-query

I am trying to write a query to compare fields in two different MongoDB collections (same DB).  Specifically, I have two collections that each contain a field that will match a portion of the time.  I would, therefore, like to iterate through each row of each collection performing a comparison.  When a match is found, I want to be able to perform a follow-on action (insert value of third field into one of the collections).  A suggestion of syntax for this comparison query would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

> You can use a $where. Just be aware it will be fairly slow (has to
>   execute Javascript code on every record) so combine with indexed
>   queries if you can.

```
db.T.find( { $where: function() { return this.Grade1 > this.Grade2 } } );
```

> or more compact:

```
db.T.find( { $where : "this.Grade1 > this.Grade2" } );
```

Comment: This still would compare data of the same collection.

Comment: Yes, this is a bad answer. How to make loops for each collection?